# Finding a conformal mapping to the unit disc, from the unit disc missing the x axis

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

I am revising conformal transformations, and am confused in general as to how to find one between two sets. I know that circlines map to circlines, but not sure how I can use that to help me with this problem.

I have the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}/ $[0,1). 
I want to map this conformally to the open unit disc. 
I can't see a way, because I don't know which 3 points would define the first set and what I would map them to.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First map your slit disk to a half-disk by $z \to \sqrt{-z}$.  Then invert around $-i$ to get a quarter-plane.  From there get a half-plane, and finally a disk.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I'm confused by what you mean by inverting "around -i"? The first map would take the set to a half disc, but I'm also confused as to which disc? Is this the disc that always has negative real values, so in the left hand side of the plane?

Comment: Inverting around $-i$ is the map $z \to 1/(z-i)$.  The principal branch of square root has positive real part.